# FatalErrorException: Input string is too long

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

I've started to build a new Laravel 5 app. I need a site message feature in my app, so I created one. But now when I'm trying to add messages into stack, I'll get the following error:

> FatalErrorException in ExceptionHandler.php line 412: Input string is
>   too long

Apache error log says:

> Mon Mar 28 20:25:40.310761 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2075:tid
>   3028430848] [client 127.0.0.1:56643] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal
>   error:  Input string is too long in
>   /Users/xxx/Development/Laravel/myapp/vendor/symfony/debug/ExceptionHandler.php
>   on line 412, referer: http://app.dev/page/new

I call Message::set method in my controller:

```
Message::set('Page created');
```

And the Message class contains:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Session;

class Message {

    const MESSAGE_INFO      = 0x1;
    const MESSAGE_WARNING   = 0x2;
    const MESSAGE_ERROR     = 0x3;

    public static function set($message, $type = MESSAGE_INFO) {
        $messages = self::get(false);
        $messages[$type][] = $message;

        Session::put('app.messages', $messages);
    }

    public static function get($flush = true) {
        $default = [ self::MESSAGE_INFO => [], self::MESSAGE_WARNING => [], self::MESSAGE_ERROR => []];

        if($flush) Session::pull('app.messages', $default);
        return Session::get('app.messages', $default);
    }

    public static function isAny() {
        $messages = self::get(false);

        foreach($messages AS $store) if(!empty($store)) return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

I'm so lost with this. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with this line:

```
public static function set($message, $type = MESSAGE_INFO) {
```

It should be:

```
public static function set($message, $type = self::MESSAGE_INFO) {
```

MESSAGE_INFO constant is defined in the Message class, not globally.

The error message was really confusing. When I put the Message::set('Page created'); call inside a try-catch block, then error message was:

> FatalErrorException in GroupManagementController.php line 45: Allowed
>   memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2890768384
>   bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong, but I'm not sure you can store an array in a Laravel session.

After you store that array in the session

```
Session::put('app.messages', $messages);
```

try to dump your session variable:

```
dd(Session::get('app.messages'));
```

Come back with the result you get so we can dig deeper.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for replying this question. There was just a little mistake in the code. The fix was added to the original post.